# Format of R's lm() Formula with a Transformation

Tags: r, linear-regression, transformation, lm

I can't quite figure out how to do the following in one line:

```
data(attenu)
x_temp = attenu$accel^(1/4)
y_temp = log(attenu$dist)
best_line = lm(y_temp ~ x_temp)
```

Since the above works, I thought I could do the following:

```
data(attenu)
best_line = lm( log(attenu$dist) ~ (attenu$accel^(1/4)) )
```

But this gives the error:

```
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : invalid power in formula
```

There's obviously something I'm missing when using transformed variables in R's formula format.  Why doesn't this work?

Comment: For future reference, you can also use `lm(log(dist) ~ I(accel^(1/4)), data=attenu)` to avoid having to do `dataset$varname` every time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking for the function `I` so that the `^` operator is treated as arithmetic in the formula, ie.

```
x <- runif(1:100)
y <- x + rnorm(100,0, 3)
lm(log(y) ~ I(x^(1/4))
```